# Asus TUF FX504 Touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, drivers, kernel, laptop

As the title says the touchpad is not working.  I currently have the Kernel version `4.15.0-42-generic` installed.

The fix is in the Kernel version `4.19.0` from [Ubuntu's MainlineBuilds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds):

```
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-headers-4.19.0-041900_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_all.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-headers-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-image-unsigned-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.19/linux-modules-4.19.0-041900-generic_4.19.0-041900.201810221809_amd64.deb
```

Would there be any impact to me upgrading to a later kernel ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there could be an impact but that doesn't mean a problem, you can always try

And if you found a problem, you can change to the previous and/or test another

Remember to choose the right version for your system and download all the required files

---

I must quote this anyway:

> By default, Ubuntu systems run with the Ubuntu kernels provided by the
>   Ubuntu repositories. However it is handy to be able to test with
>   unmodified upstream kernels to help locate problems in Ubuntu kernel
>   patches, or to confirm that upstream has fixed a specific issue. To
>   this end we now offer select upstream kernel builds. These kernels are
>   made from unmodified kernel source but using the Ubuntu kernel
>   configuration files. These are then packaged as Ubuntu .deb files for
>   simple installation, saving you the time of compiling kernels, and
>   debugging build issues.
>
> These kernels are not supported and are not appropriate for production
>   use.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: Yeah, and adding to this, you can try with any kernel listed [here](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/). You just need to select the correct files. Sometimes it's good to check other users experience with those kernels since there may be problems booting up with some kernel versions.

Comment: And to install the Deb files the best way is is an app like gdebi or using this command: `sudo apt install ./linux*.deb` (be sure there aren't any other Deb files in the same folder to avoid errors).